# Go Heroku Tutorial: No such file or directory: runtime.h

Tags: heroku, go

I'm working on the Golang Heroku tutorial right now, and I'm at this step:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go#prepare-the-app

When I execute the following:

```
go get github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/cmd/...
```

I get this error:

```
# runtime/cgo
/tmp/go-build867338420/runtime/cgo/_obj/_cgo_defun.c:4 6c: No such file or directory: runtime.h
```

Here is my go environment:

```
    GOARCH="amd64"
    GOBIN=""
    GOCHAR="6"
    GOEXE=""
    GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
    GOHOSTOS="linux"
    GOOS="linux"
    GOPATH="/home/crystal/go/"
    GORACE=""
    GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
    GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
    TERM="dumb"
    CC="gcc"
    GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
    CXX="g++"
    CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

What could potentially be the issue here?

Comment: I think this is a combination of an old version of Go, and GOROOT having been moved from the default build location. Try updating Go first.

Comment: Building on @JimB's comment: Heroku only supports Go 1.5.3 and Go 1.6 as per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-support#supported-versions - if you're on an older Linux distro (Debian <= 7, Ubuntu <= 15.04) then you won't have a recent enough version installed. See here for the latest releases: https://golang.org/dl/